# How to test an API endpoint for an error path that can be triggered by more than one code paths?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, mocha.js, sinon

Say, there are multiple paths in a function that would lead to a server error(500). So in a unit test:

1. is it enough to just trigger the error from any single path?
2. while asserting is it enough to just assert for a 500 error code or is it required to also assert for the expected error?

What I mean (in code)?

```
it('should trigger server error', async function() {

  // arrange
  const res = { 
    status: this.sandbox.stub().returnsThis(),
    json: this.sandbox.stub(),
  }; 
  const req = {
    body: { name: 'foo', email: 'foo@bar.com', password: 'password' },
  };
  // switch on one possible trigger path that would lead to 500 error
  const expectedError = new Error('Server Error');
  this.sandbox.stub(User, 'createWithPassword').rejects(expectedError);

  // act
  await userApi.create(req, res);

  // assert
  // is this assertion enough ?
  expect(res.status).to.have.been.calledWith(500);
  // also should this go along with the above? 
  expect(res.json).to.have.been.calledWith(expectedError);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decouple error handling and your user controller/business logic. Your user controller shouldn't have to worry about handling the errors.

Write separate error handling middleware that will handle any errors:

```
module.handleErrors = (error, req, res, next) => {
  // Handle error
  // ...

  res.status(500).json()
}
```

But now we need a way to catch any errors that occur in the controller. So we need another middleware to catch errors and forward the errors to the above error handling middleware:

```
module.catchErrors = controllerAction => (req, res, next) => controllerAction(req, res).catch(next)
```

Now we can wire up the middleware starting with the global error handler:

```
const express = require('express)
const { handleErrors } = require('./error-middleware)
const { userRoutes } = require('./user-routes)

const app = express()

app.use('/users', userRoutes)
app.use(handleErrors)

// ..
```

Next wire up the user routes and controller to catch the errors:

```
const express = require('express')
const userController = require('./user-controller')
const { catchErrors } = require('./error-middleware')

const router = express.Router()

// Passing the createWithPassword function to the catch error middleware.
router.post('/', catchErrors(userController.createWithPassword))

module.exports = router
```

Now that everything is decoupled, you're free to test each piece in isolation for your unit tests. Integration tests is where you'd test for many scenarios. So:

1. With the above setup I described, we don't *need* to test every single scenarios since ultimately any errors would be caught by the error handling middleware. All we care is that it is handled properly when an error arises.
2. It depends on your requirements. If all you're doing is throwing an exception with no clear message/reason, then checking for `500` and the type will suffice. But if you're expecting *specific* errors to occur during *specific* operations, then it would be test to test the error message, exception, HTTP status, and more.

Comment: Thanks for showing how to decouple error handling from controllers.  Tests are now laid out much better with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, you should test every path. You should even run your unit tests under a code coverage tool (e.g. [istanbul](https://www.npmjs.com/package/istanbul)) so you make sure to cover all paths. This is all about [cyclomatic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity); the more paths you have the more tests you need to cover everything. It is good to keep it low.
2. Asserting for just the type of the error is OK, but you better assert for every specific error to make sure that with time you do not introduce a bug that make one condition throw the other error. You will have a false positive test pass in this case.

Comment: Thanks @Renato for your pointers. I did encounter false positive tests when assertions are more generic. I normally keep my functions small but in rest API endpoints, I normally have one success path & 2 error paths. Istanbul reports help a lot in finding the missing paths.